# If the graph of the function f(x) = $2x^3+ax^2+bx , a,b \in N$ cut the x -axis at three distinct points,

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If the graph of the function f(x) = $2x^3+ax^2+bx , a,b \in N$ cut the x -axis at three distinct points, then find the maximum values of a+b.

Please suggest as I am not getting any clue on this how to proceed such problem. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the max or min value of $a+b$. Seems to me, you can have $a+b$ as large as you please, but the min is $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write
$$
f(x) = x(2x^2 + ax + b) = (x - 0) (2x^2 + ax + b)
$$

Is zero a root of $f$?

What are the roots of $f$ other than zero (in terms of $a$ and $b$)?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your function as follows:
$$f(x) = x(2x^2+ax+b)$$
Clearly, $f(x_0) = 0$ with $x_0 = 0$.
Now, you have two more solutions if $2x^2+ax+b = 0$ has 2 solutions. This happens when the discriminant is positive. That is:

$$\Delta = a^2 - 8b > 0.$$

Since both $a$ and $b$ are natural, then the previous is equivalent to:

$$\Delta = a^2 - 8b \geq 1.$$

Fixing $a \in \mathbb{N}$, then you have that:
$$1 \leq b \leq \left\lfloor\frac{a^2 + 1}{8} \right\rfloor$$

Having fixed $a$, the greatest $b$ possible is

$$b = \left\lfloor\ \frac{a^2 + 1}{8} \right\rfloor$$

Thus, the maximum of $a+b$ with $a$ fixed is

$$a + \left\lfloor\ \frac{a^2+1}{8} \right\rfloor$$

If $a$ is not fixed, then $a+b$ is unbounded and there is no maximum, since $a$ can be arbitrarily large.